# How to insert a break tag between text with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Updated

The following is an output from a old CMS.
I would like to insert a break tag after 'Klikk her om du er privatkunde!
'.

From this,

```
<TR>
 <TD CLASS="td-main" COLSPAN="6">
 <A HREF="link to some page">Other link here.</A>
 <A HREF="link to some page">There could be other link, but may be.</A>
 </TD>
 </TR>
...
 <TR>
 <TD CLASS="td-main" COLSPAN="6">
 <A HREF="edit-8.asp?CustType=1">Klikk her om du er privatkunde</A>!
 <A HREF="edit-8.asp?CustType=2">Klikk her om du er bedriftskunde</A>!
 </TD>
 </TR>
...
```

to this.

```
...
...
...
<TR>
<TD CLASS="td-main" COLSPAN="6">
<A HREF="edit-8.asp?CustType=1">Klikk her om du er privatkunde</A>!

<br />

<A HREF="edit-8.asp?CustType=2">Klikk her om du er bedriftskunde</A>!
</TD>
</TR>
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it please?

Thanks in advance.

What I came up is this, but it does not work.

```
if(location.pathname.indexOf('edit-8') > 0){
$('td[value|=Klikk her om du er privatkunde!]').replaceWith('Klikk her om 
du er privatkunde!<br />')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If selecting by the `href` is unique, you can use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for this:

```
$("a[href='edit-8.asp?CustType=2']").before("<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery chain below does this:

1. Finds any `<a>` tag with the text 'Klikk her om du er privatkunde' inside of it.
2. Looks for an `<a>` following it.
3. Inserts a `<br>` element before the 2nd `<a>` tag.

I was originally just going to insert the `<br>` tag directly after the `<a>` which contained the matching text, but if I did that, it would have inserted the line break before the `!` which was outside of that tag.

```
$(function() {
  if (location.pathname.indexOf("edit-8") > -1) {
    $("a:contains('Klikk her om du er privatkunde')").next("a").before("<br/>");
  };
});
```

***Opinion.*** This is really wonky. What happens if that text gets changed? I wouldn't want to maintain that website.

Comment: Agreed. Also, what if the the `a` after the link of interest is deleted?... who knows where that line break will end up then.